# Cannot Open .png file with CImg on CLion (macOS)

Tags: c++, macos, png, clion, cimg

I've tried including libpng16/png.h and #define cimg_use_png, but none of them solved the error. Also, I have main.cpp, lenna.jpg and CImg.h in the same directory.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(HelloWorld ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(YOU_NEED_X11 1)
set(YOU_NEED_PNG 1)

if (${YOU_NEED_PNG} EQUAL 1)
    message(STATUS "Looking for libpng...")
    find_package(PNG REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries (HelloWorld ${PNG_LIBRARY})
    target_compile_definitions(HelloWorld PRIVATE cimg_use_png=1)
endif()

if (${YOU_NEED_X11} EQUAL 1)
    message(STATUS "Looking for X11...")
    find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
    include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
    target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${X11_LIBRARIES})
else()
    target_compile_definitions(HelloWorld PRIVATE cimg_display=0)
endif()
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "CImg.h"

using namespace cimg_library;

int main() {

    CImg<unsigned char> img("lenna.png");

    int h = img.height();
    int w = img.width();
    int s = img.spectrum();

    std::cout << "h: " << h << " w: " << w << " s: " << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
[CImg] *** CImgIOException *** [instance(0,0,0,0,0x0,non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to open file 'lenna.png'.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cimg_library::CImgIOException: [instance(0,0,0,0,0x0,non-shared)] CImg<unsigned char>::load(): Failed to open file 'lenna.png'.

Process finished with exit code 6
```

Comment: Wait a second, are you trying to use libpng to open a jpeg?

Comment: Try running `file lenna.png` to see if it is a PNG or a JPEG as you seem a little unsure.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the command shows: **lenna.png: PNG image data, 512 x 512, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced**.

Comment: @Kerndog73 it's a .png

Comment: Please run `ls -l | pbcopy` in the directory where you are working and then click `edit` under your question. Paste in the code with Cmd+V and then select the newly-pasted code and click the `{}` in the formatting toolbar (near **Bold** and *Italic*) to format the directory listing as code. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run ```ls -l | pbcopy```.

Comment: It loads the output into the clipboard ready for pasting in the next step.

Comment: @GabrielS Could you please complete the steps described by Mark? I think it could be helpful. Also, why does your question mention `lenna.jpg`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `lenna.png` is not being found. Relative paths are relative to the directory containing the executable. That means that if the executable is at `cmake-build-debug/HelloWorld` and you try to open `lenna.png`, the file at `cmake-build-debug/lenna.png` is opened. This means that you should either manually copy `lenna.png` into `cmake-build-debug` (I don't recommend this) or ask CMake to do it for you.

Add this to your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

```
add_custom_command(
      TARGET HelloWorld POST_BUILD
      COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
              ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lenna.png
              ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lenna.png
)
```

This will cause `lenna.png` to be copied into the same directory as your executable every time the executable is compiled.

Comment: Now the error log says: **Failed to recognize format of file 'lenna.png'.**